# Join table, for which the table name has to be grabbed in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

This question is not to discuss if the setup of the DB is as it should be, i'm not happy with how it is, but it is how it is and a refactor will not be done by the DBA at this moment.

What i am looking for is a way to join a table, for which i do not in advance know the table name but it is in the table i want to do the join against.

So:

```
TABEL transactions
trans_id  autherizer
001Bar    payment_provider_a
001Foo    payment_provider_b


TABLE payment_provider_a
trans_id  amount
001Bar    50


TABLE payment_provider_b
trans_id  amount
001Foo    50
```

The table names are fictional, but the setup is identical. There is a `transaction` table, which stores an `transaction_id` and a `payment_provider` string name (with a lot of additional data, which is not relevant for the question).

Would there be anyway to get all the data from the `transaction` table and in that query do directly a `join` on the payment_provider table, for which we only now what that table can be from the `transaction` table.

I have tagged it with PHP as well, since i want to make the call with `PDO`. Whole PHP snippets are not required, but if you insist ;). A push in the right direction for the query it self would be sufficient. I am aware that i am lacking the example of what i have tried. But to be honest i haven't tried that much because i can't really think of something, it's the first time i am in this kind of need for such a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not overly clean, but you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t JOIN
    (
        SELECT 'payment_provider_a' AS name,* FROM payment_provider_a
    UNION
        SELECT 'payment_provider_b' AS name,* FROM payment_provider_b
    ) p ON t.payment_provider = p.name AND t.trans_id=p.trans_id
```

Note that all `payment_provider_x` tables must have the same number and types of columns. Otherwise you'll need to select only the fields that are actually common (there are ways around this if needed).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it won't change the results (as the name is different anyway), but it should indeed help a bit with performance.

Comment: I have accepted it as the answer, but this ain't going to work for me, every time there is a new payment provider introduced, i will have to change / update the query.. I will just do two queries and the second will be the final. Thank you.

Comment: A few things you can do: 1. add a new table for all new payment providers, which includes the name/id of the payment provider (so you add that table in the union, without the need to insert the name) or 2. create a view on the server with has the union of all those tables. That way when you add a new payment provider you just need to update the view, not the code.